# margin offset Sticky header scrolling issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

so I have a sticky header on a website project that is using single page layout as expected. Just because my header is quite big because of the logo, whenever I scroll it covers the headers of each section. I was wondering is it a way to offset the margin whenever a link is clicked on scroll with like margin-top: 150px;. I also have a content that is using absolute position and I want to specify another selector that is only scrolling on fixed with for a specific page-section. I hope that makes sense, I will post a part of the html and jquery code that I have so far:

HTML:

```
    <header>
            <div class="container-fluid example5">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default navigation1">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                            <button type="button" id="nav-toggle" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar5"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
                            <a class="navbar-brand scroll-top" href="index.html"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/Logo3.png" alt="Cleaning Services Logo"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="navbar5" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li class="active"><a class="scroll-link" data-id="home" href="#carousel-example">HOME</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#about" class="scroll-link" data-id="about">ABOUT</a></li>
                                <li><a href=".services" class="scroll-link" data-id="services">SERVICES</a></li>
                                <li><a class="red scroll-link" data-id="hot-offers" href=".hot-offers">HOT OFFERS</a></li>
                                <li><a href=".testimonials" class="scroll-link" data-id="testimonials">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
                                <li><a href=".contact-us" class="scroll-link" data-id="contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
                    </div>
                    <!--/.container-fluid -->
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
<!-- content -->
<div id="#carousel-example" class="page-section">
<h1>Header</h1>
<p>CONTENT....</p>
</div>
<div id="about" class="page-section"><h2>Header</h2>
<p>CONTENT....</p></div>
<div id=".services" class="page-section"><h3>Header</h3>
<p>CONTENT....</p></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var curLink = $(this);
                var scrollPoint = $(curLink.attr('href')).position().top;
                $('body,html').animate({
                    scrollTop: scrollPoint
                }, 500);
            })
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                onScrollHandle();
            });

            function onScrollHandle() {
                //Navbar shrink when scroll down
                $(".navbar-default").toggleClass("navbar-shrink", $(this).scrollTop() > 50);
                //Get current scroll position
                var currentScrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
                //Iterate through all node
                $('#navbar5 > ul > li > a').each(function () {
                    var curLink = $(this);
                    var refElem = $(curLink.attr('href'));
                    //Compare the value of current position and the every section position in each scroll
                    if (refElem.position().top <= currentScrollPos && refElem.position().top + refElem.height() > currentScrollPos) {
                        //Remove class active in all nav
                        $('#navbar5 > ul > li').removeClass("active");
                        //Add class active
                        curLink.parent().addClass("active");
                    }
                    else {
                        curLink.parent().removeClass("active");
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: edit your question, add your code to a "snippet", explain, cause what you said is like Chinese to me (sorry Asians nothing personal)

Comment: When I click on link it scrolls to the page-section as it should, I only need when I click on it to scroll again on the page-section but with offset of margin-top:100px; so the header can be visible . Does that make sense now?

Comment: make complete sense!

Comment: but your code is far from working, your html is crash, and doesn't go with your js

Answer (score 0):

Coudn't understand what exactly you want, but for a beginnig let's try to make your code works first,
i removed the `scrollHandle()` function, and corrected your `html`,
now try to explain to me what you want and i'll edit my answer.

```js
$('a').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var curLink = $(this);
                var scrollPoint = $(curLink.attr('href')).position().top;
                $('body,html').animate({
                    scrollTop: scrollPoint
                }, 500);
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
            <div class="container-fluid example5">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default navigation1">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                            <button type="button" id="nav-toggle" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar5"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
                            <a class="navbar-brand scroll-top" href="index.html"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/Logo3.png" alt="Cleaning Services Logo"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="navbar5" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li class="active"><a class="scroll-link" data-id="home" href="#carousel-example">HOME</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#about" class="scroll-link" data-id="about">ABOUT</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#services" class="scroll-link" data-id="services">SERVICES</a></li>
                                <li><a class="red scroll-link" data-id="hot-offers" href="#hot-offers">HOT OFFERS</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#testimonials" class="scroll-link" data-id="testimonials">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#contact-us" class="scroll-link" data-id="contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
                    </div>
                    <!--/.container-fluid -->
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
<!-- content -->

<div id="about" class="page-section"><h2>about</h2>
<p>CONTENT....</p></div>
<div id="services" class="page-section"><h3>services</h3>
<p>CONTENT....</p></div>
<div id="hot-offers" class="page-section"><h3>Hot Offers</h3>
<p>CONTENT....</p></div>
<div id="testimonials" class="page-section"><h3>testimonials</h3>
<p>CONTENT....</p></div>
<div id="contact-us" class="page-section"><h3>Contact US</h3>
<p>CONTENT....</p></div>
<div style="height:300px"/>
```